# Target HTML Background based on class

Tags: html, css

**My goal:**

> To use css to select the html tag with 2 different selectors based upon class.

**My issue:**

> It seems as though the HTML tag can't be selected with a class as well on CSS.

**What I have Tried:**

Option 1:

```
.light-theme html {
  background: #fff;
}
.dark-theme html {
  background: #000;
}
```

Option 2:

```
html .light-theme {
  background: #fff;
}
html .dark-theme {
  background: #000;
}
```

Option 3 (hack to get around original issue:

```
.light-theme {
  background: #fff;
}
.dark-theme {
  background: #000;
}
```

**My results:**

[Option 1](http://codepen.io/Pachonk/pen/VeaRMZ) and Option 2 do not work at at while [Option 3](http://codepen.io/Pachonk/pen/adNMVP) work fine, but never includes the HTML as a selector.

**My question:**

> Is it even possible to use classes as a css selector for the html tag using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html.light-theme {
  background: #fff;
}
html.dark-theme {
  background: #000;
}
```

`html.light-theme` means select `html` tag with class `light-theme`

Comment: So I guess it was just me using poor CSS selectors.